# What layout is this?

Tags: anova, experiment-design

A fleet of electric vehicles are to be investigated for the mileage performance per
charge. Four vehicles have been chosen randomly from the fleet and four observations of miles were made for each vehicle. The data obtained from the experiment are below.

| vehicle | obs 1 | obs 2 | obs 3 | obs 4 | charging time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 98 | 97 | 99 | 96 | 25 |
| 2 | 91 | 90 | 93 | 92 | 20 |
| 3 | 96 | 95 | 97 | 95 | 23 |
| 4 | 95 | 96 | 99 | 98 | 30 |

What type of experimental design is this? What is the model and associated hypothesis?

I have thought it over a lot but I am not sure which layout to use. First I thought it would be a two-way unreplicated anova but the charging time is unique for each vehicle. Then I tried blocking but I am not sure how to block in this setting. I am really lost here.

Comment: Transform your data from wide to long format and it will be clearer.